# Half of the world masked when using maskoceans in Basemap

Tags: python, plot, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to mask oceans when plotting the data from a netCDF dataset. I followed the great instructions given [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996071/plotting-oceans-in-maps-using-basemap-and-python/32120065#32120065). It works great for half of the world, but somehow, everything west of Greenwich is masked as well, both ocean and land.
Here is my code:

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import mpl_toolkits
from mpl_toolkits import basemap
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, maskoceans

filename = 'myfile.nc'
vmin = 0.
vmax = 1

nc = netCDF4.Dataset(filename, 'r')
data = nc.variables['sum'][:]  
lats_1d = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lons_1d = nc.variables['lon'][:]
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons_1d, lats_1d)

labels = ['DJF', 'MAM', 'JJA', 'SON']
cmap = cm.RdYlBu
cmap.set_over('#00FF00')

my_dpi = 96

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1200/my_dpi, 800./my_dpi))
for season in range(4):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, season+1)
    map1 = basemap.Basemap(resolution='c', projection='kav7', lon_0=0)
    map1.drawcoastlines()
    map1.drawcountries()

    nc_new = maskoceans(lons,lats,data[season,:,:],resolution='c', grid = 1.25)
    datapc = map1.pcolormesh(lons, lats, nc_new,  vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap=cmap, latlon=True)

    plt.title(labels[season])

fig.tight_layout(pad=1, w_pad=1, h_pad=4)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.52, 0.9, 0.025])
cb = plt.colorbar(cax=ax, orientation='horizontal', cmap=cmap,
                  extend='max', format="%.2f",
                  ticks=[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1])

plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting image]

I know that a somewhat similar issue was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34153455/maskoceans-with-no-ocean-in-mask-and-no-data) but never got answered, and it appears that in the end, the problem was mixing up lat-long coordinates with x-y ones. I tried switching to x-y coordinates but got the same half-map. Any idea of what can be happening here?

**N.B.** when plotting the unmasked data using `datapc = map1.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data[season,:,:], vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap=cmap, latlon=True)` the whole world is plotted (land + oceans).

Comment: Do you have a version of `myfile.nc` you can post anywhere to allow the problem to be reproduced?  Or a cut down version?  Here's a first guess - your data might run 0-360 degrees instead of -180 to +180 degrees.  That's just a guess at this stage, but it's pretty clear that what should be at longitudes -180 to 0 are not being plotted.  Assuming they're in your data, they must be being masked or discarded for some reason.  If you can't show `myfile.nc`, can you output `print(max(lons),min(lons))` in the loop?

Comment: Indeed, my data runs from 0 to 360, and not from -180 to 180. However, when plotting the unmasked data using
`datapc = map1.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data[season,:,:],  vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, cmap=cmap, latlon=True)`
the whole world is plotted (land + oceans) so I didn't think that it was the problem. How can I adjust this? Should it be done for the mask or the data?

Comment: *try* (just a suggestion) doing `lons_1d[lons_1d>180]-=360` just after you pull out `lons_1d` from `nc`.  It's a bit cryptic, but just uses numpy fancy indexing to conditionally change the values between 180 and 360.  Hope that will do the trick.  If not - I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: It worked! Fast and easy fix, but I would have never thought of that...! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have the same problem, but when I use the suggestion (lons_1d[lons_1d>180]-=360), appears ''WARNING: x coordinate not monotonically increasing - contour plot may not be what you expect.  If it looks odd, your can either adjust the map projection region to be consistent with your data or (if your data is on a global lat/lon grid) use the shift grid function to adjust the data to be consistent with the map projection region (see examples/contour_demo.py).'' And the figure changed, with strips and totally wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've identified, the points with longitudes -180 to 0 are not being plotted. Assuming they're in your data, they must be being masked or discarded for some reason.

My intuition was that the dataset longitudes ran 0-360 instead of -180 to 180, which was [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070153/half-of-the-world-masked-when-using-maskoceans-in-basemap#comment59788502_36070153) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070153/half-of-the-world-masked-when-using-maskoceans-in-basemap#comment59788443_36070153).

The quick fix for this is to add

```
lons_1d[lons_1d>180]-=360
```

just after you pull out `lons_1d` from `nc`.  This works because `lons_1d` is a numpy array and it uses numpy [boolean array indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) (often called "fancy" indexing) to conditionally select the longitude values greater than 180 and subtract 360 from them.

As you note that the `pcolormesh` plot works if you omit the mask, this looks like a bug with wrapping in the `maskoceans` function, or at least unexpected behaviour.

For reference - I do not think you are the first to experience similar "wrapping" type issues with masks, I think this [issue on the matplotlib github](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/54) looks rather similar.