# How to retrieve longitude and latitude value from a NetCDF variable?

Tags: netcdf

I have read  a netcdf file of observed climate data and I would like to plot some species locality data (latitude/longitude coordinate points)

Is the longitude & latitude value will be change based on NetCDF variables ?

Answer (score 1):

If all your variables are in the same `netcdf` file, they will all share the same coordinates system, and the lat and long are available in their own subfile within your `netcdf` file.

Comment: Thank Cynthia. Do u know matrix order of storing data in NetCDF file ?

Comment: Latitude is usually 90 to -90, but for longitude, I found that it varies: either 0 to 360 or -180 to 180, but it's usually easy to find out which one (Half of the world might be missing if you use the wrong coordinate system, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070153/half-of-the-world-masked-when-using-maskoceans-in-basemap)

Comment: I tired this NetCDF dataset - http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep/rhum.sfc.day.ltm.nc  but the actual result is like : rhum.rhum[365][73][144]
[0][0], -23626, -23626, -23626, -23626, -23626, -23626, -23626.            I didn't getting this results when am using Spark

Comment: I don't use Spark, so not sure why there should be a difference, but your grid is probably not at 1deg resolution, so I'm guessing that the 73 and 144 are you lat and long? The link you shared doesn't work.

Comment: i will send up the updated link : http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/ncep/rhum.sfc.day.ltm.nc.html.

Comment: I would like to know how NetCDF data represented in matrix format ?