# Cannot render North America data with Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I want to render an entire map and parts of North America using a netcdf file from **European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts** but only half of the map is shown.

```py
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

fn = '_grib2netcdf-webmars-public-svc-green-007-6fe5cac1a363ec1525f54343b6cc9fd8-b5oXS9.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(fn)

#variables
#longitude, latitude, time, pm1

lons = ds.variables['longitude'][:]
lats = ds.variables['latitude'][:]
time = ds.variables['time'][:]
pm = ds.variables['pm1'][:]

mp = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-80,urcrnrlat=80,\
            llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')

lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = mp(lon, lat)

cscheme = mp.pcolor(x, y, np.squeeze(pm[0,:,:]), cmap = 'plasma', shading='auto')
mp.drawcoastlines()
mp.drawstates()
mp.drawcountries()

cbar = mp.colorbar(cscheme, location = 'right')
plt.title('Particulate matter d < 1 um')
plt.show()
```

Here is the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/guJx8.png

I checked the netcdf file with [**Panoply**](https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) and looks fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBUZD.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Half of the world masked when using maskoceans in Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070153/half-of-the-world-masked-when-using-maskoceans-in-basemap)

Comment: yes, but only shows the half of the map: https://i.imgur.com/jFnzGXx.png

Comment: Is that a "Yes, but no"? You seem to have placed an Answer to your own Question saying it did solve your issue.

Comment: I want the American data, and got it with that solution, it's a Yes, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
lons[lons>180]-=360
```

From
[Half of the world masked when using maskoceans in Basemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070153/half-of-the-world-masked-when-using-maskoceans-in-basemap)